# How to decrease time of request tried to get executed?

Tags: c#, gmail-api

I'm using gmail api and trying to get count of messages. If problems with internet connection happens `Execute()` trying to get executed more than 1 minute. I want to skip executing after 5 seconds without response and not wait anymore.

```
var getEmailsRequest = new UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest(service, userId);
try
{
    messagesCount = getEmailsRequest.Execute().Messages.Count;
}
catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
{
    //after more than minute of waiting with no connection I can catch this exception
}
```

Comment: @Stefan Google.Apis.Gmail.v1

Comment: Are you using the HttpClientFactory? If so, please show use your initialization routines

Comment: @Stefan No I'm not using it

Comment: Ok, I must say I am not familiar with the library, but it seems it has an `ExecuteAsync` as well, which you can provide a cancelation token, is that correct?

Comment: @Stefan Yes, I see ExecuteAsync is available

Comment: I updated my answer to support a cancelation token, it might be tricky if the calling method isn't using a `async Task` signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I know nothing of the library in question ;-)

---

If you are using [googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client)
:

Then your should be able to configure a timeout with [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/2df445ea9fce00868cf0a1ea010cb40ef6ed64a8/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Core/Http/IConfigurableHttpClientInitializer.cs):

```
/// <summary> 
/// HTTP client initializer for changing the default behavior of HTTP client. 
/// Use this initializer to change default values like timeout and number of tries. 
/// You can also set different handlers and interceptors like 
/// <see cref="IHttpUnsuccessfulResponseHandler"/>s, 
/// <see cref="IHttpExceptionHandler"/>s and <see cref="IHttpExecuteInterceptor"/>s.
/// </summary>
public interface IConfigurableHttpClientInitializer
{
    /// <summary>Initializes a HTTP client after it was created.</summary>
    void Initialize(ConfigurableHttpClient httpClient);
}
```

---

As alternative, you can use `ExecuteAsync`with the cancelation token, e.g.:

```
CancellationTokenSource source = 
             new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000));

var someResult = await getEmailsRequest.ExecuteAsync(source.Token);
messagesCount = someResult.Messages.Count;
```

Do note, for this to work you need an `async Task` as method signature.